Can search inside collapsed details tag automatically expand that tag?
Browser search (Ctrl-F) for text inside a closed <details> tag does not work consistently. In current Chromium (128), and I believe Edge, the browser will find a match inside such a tag, open it, and navigate there. In current Firefox (115, 131), and I believe Safari, the browser will not search inside closed tags. Is there a way to configure Firefox to search inside closed tags? If not, is there an event I could capture to try to re-do the search in my own code (worst case, expanding all closed tags myself first)?

Go to a site containing a closed details tag, such as https://css-tricks.com/exploring-what-the-details-and-summary-elements-can-do/, in both Chromium and Firefox.

Perform a browser search (Ctrl-F) for "BYOB" (without the quotes), which is text in the closed tag.

Expected: Browser finds text, expands the closed tag, highlights the search query, and navigates there.

Chromium: As expected.
Firefox: Browser does nothing and indicates it's failed to find a match (pink background in searchbox).



